# the "properties bar" of android studio layout sidebar can't remove from sidebar

Tags: android, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWJB4.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skdQG.png)

I update Android Studio to 2.2.3 today and when I'm going to layout xml file. I choosed "Design" tab once time, and back to "Text" tab, then the Properties sidebar show automaticly and I click "remove from sidebar","properties" disappear immediatly but when I reopen an xml file and it will show again!(AS always show "Preview" tab at first in yesterday)

Is it a bug of AS 2.2.3?

Comment: I have the same issue, properties sidebar appear every time xml file is open...